# Setup Postfix to catch emails received to a Java program

Tags: postfix, java

I would like to configure my PostFix server to forward every emails received to a Java instance, I found some virtual domain config but I don't know how to plug it to my Java instance.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: see the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561011/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-a-java-application-to-receive-incoming-email

Answer (score 0):

Things you may have a look at:

- route mail to account and use pop/imap to fetch mail into your programm
- setup you programm to receive mail through lmtp like dovecot does
- have a look at master.cf and integrate your programm there
- transport pipe may also be a solution

Not sure what is right for your problem you need to solve. Depends a lot on volume of mails and what Java supports here.

Comment: TabTwo, mail volumes may be quite important...and my Java Program will be a Tomcat web app, I'll have a look at the different solutions you are mentioning

Comment: Personaly, if volume is not to high, I would go the POP way. All the complexity with mailhandlling linke bounces, headers ... is handled by software that does this job 10+ years. Plus, it would be very easy to adapt to different enviroments, all you need is a server you can fetch mail from, be it Lotus, Exchange ... and probably way faster to implement/poc. @JanPI s link may be what you were looking for.

Comment: yes I think you're right, Will go deeper on JanPi's link.